# How to deploy frontend and backend ECS services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am new to ECS. I have an Apollo React web app client and an Apollo Express server API. I have deployed React client (`:80`) successfully via ECS Getting Started. Also configured HTTPS and it can be accessed at `https://my-application/`

Now I am trying to deploy API server (`:8081`). I created a new task definition and created a new service by following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Kr_455zMk4

I chose `80:HTTP` for **Production listener port** and **same load balancer name** with React client, created a new target group: `ecs-default-cluster-server-api`. **Path pattern**: `/server-api*` and `1` for **Evaluation order**. However it does not work for me.

I want to deploy server API at `https://api.my-application/` or any other suitable path. How do I do it?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you mean by that it "does not work for me"? Do you get any errors, timeouts, and more?

Comment: When I go to the `https://my-application/server-api`, it shows `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` and `502 Bad Gateway` at `https://my-application/server-api/`. Service and task show RUNNING status in ECS.

Comment: Can you edit your question with details of your load balancer and target group settings?

Comment: I recorded the process of creating a new service, https://imgur.com/CfHZFFc. Just to simplify, this time I created a service for React app (:3000) along side with Gatsby page (:80) `https://my-app.com` . I want newly created React app available at `https://new.my-app.com`. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I see. I've noticed that you set HTTPS for target group? Are your containers actually listening on 443 and have private ssl certificates setup? For moment I think I saw your containers with HTTP and port 80?

Comment: Hey, @Marcin. After browsing some hands-on tutorials from AWS, I realized that my architect is crap. So I am now restarting from scratch. Thank you so much for your answers.